# Unity - Loading .obj files from an external source during runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it in any way possible to load objects that are not within the project itself during runtime in a Unity project? Importing from an assets bundle is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to import an asset from the Unity assets store to do the importing job for you.
There are free ones, like the [Runtime OBJ Importer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547).

Experiment with different ones and see what suits you most!
Good luck :)